# Eclipse Jetty Integration start.ini

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

I'm using Eclipse Jetty Integration plugin .

But I cannot specify my start.ini.

How do I specify start.ini ?

---

## env

Windows 10, Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2

Comment: Hi, you find a solution for that? Eclipse with jetty 9 no read start.ini neither  JVM property -Djava.security.auth.login.config=

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its possible but as an workaround, you can supply those config properties via 
VM arguments:

right_click_on_your_project->run_as->run_configuration->jetty_webapp->server_instance->Arguments->VM_arguments

```
-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.annotations.maxWait=120
```

Apply and Run.hope it helps.

[image]